# jQuery: Post key/pair list to ASP.NET MVC controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, jquery

I've searched StackOverflow regarding posting a kep/pair list of data to a MVC controller. All related posts don't cover key/pair lists and Bing is not helping either. Here is my sample code:

**Controller**

```
    <HttpPost>
    Public Function Update(cart As List(Of String)) As JsonResult
        Dim x = 55
    End Function
```

**JS**

```
    list = new Array();
    list.push({ "SKU": 1, "Quantity": 1 });
    list.push({ "SKU": 2, "Quantity": 2 });
    list.push({ "SKU": 3, "Quantity": 5 });

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        url: 'something.com/controller/poo',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: me.attr('href'),
        data: JSON.stringify({ cart: list }),
        success: function (data) {
            console.debug(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.debug(data);
        }
    });
```

The value of *cart* in the controller is nothing. I'm at a loss to understand why. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you're forgotting to specify on your ajax call that you're sending a contentType: 'json'. Also, doing that you shouldn't need to stringify your json object before sending it to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try todictionary and its effect when submitting json value to controller.

[$.toDictionary](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2010/12/sending-complex-json-objects-to-aspnet.html)